# Python GPIO-hardware-button to start a program

Tags: python, daemon, gpio, autostart

I wrote a small script to start a pythonscript by pressing a button, which is connected to a GPIO and GND on my RasPi:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def main():
    while True:
        input_state = GPIO.input(18)
        if input_state == False:
            print('Button Pressed')
            os.system("/home/pi/bootF.py")
            time.sleep(0.2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That works totally fine, but when I add the script to my rc.local

```
    /bin/sleep 20 && python /home/pi/buttonResponse.py & #also tried sudo python
```

and it gets a PID after boot nothing happens when I hit the button. I believe that has something to do with sudo, but I do not have an idea at the moment how to manage this. Again, starting manually with "sudo python buttonResponse.py" works at this point.

This is how my grep looks like after boot (button doesnt work):

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ps -ef | grep python
    root      2372     1  1 07:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python -O /usr/share/wicd/daemon/wicd-daemon.py
    root      2402     1 69 07:49 ?        00:00:54 python /home/pi/buttonResponse.py
    root      2438  2372  1 07:49 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/python -O /usr/share/wicd/daemon/monitor.py
    pi        2478  2456  0 07:50 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto python
```

And this is how my grep looks like after starting the script manually, empty rc.local (works!):

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ps -ef | grep python                                         root      2372     1  1 07:54 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python -O /usr/share/wicd/daemon/wicd-daemon.py
root      2435  2372  2 07:54 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/python -O /usr/share/wicd/daemon/monitor.py
root      2466  2445  0 07:55 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo python buttonResponse.py
root      2467  2466 90 07:55 pts/0    00:00:21 python buttonResponse.py
pi        2493  2476  0 07:55 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto python
```

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Try using an absolute path in the call of `boofF.py`

Comment: Just tried, but it didnt solved the problem. :-(